# How does Google Analytics aggregate the Count of Visits (Frequency & Recency Report)?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Here's **my simple understanding** of Count of Visits:

Each person that comes to my site gets one "count" for each visit.  They are put into a bucket of people with the same number of total counts -- if you visit twice, you are in the two bucket, if you visit six times, you are in the six bucket.  From there, a report (Frequency & Recency) makes a line for each bucket and reaches into the bucket and totals the number of people in that bucket, putting that total in the second column.

**My Question**: Will a two month report automatically put someone into two buckets, and put them on two separate lines in the Count of Visits table?

[This explaination](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1032796) makes it seem like a two-month long report *will* put the same person into a bucket twice, one bucket for each month.  The two-month report will then show that person's visits on two different lines, instead of aggregating them.

**Example for Clarification**: Bob comes to my site three times in January and seven times in February.  I run a report for Jan 1 -- Feb 28.  Will Bob be on *both* the Three Count line and the Seven Count line, or will he be on the Ten Count line?

Comment: The way I understand it would put them together on one line, if you wanted them separately you would have to pull individual months.

Comment: @VincePettit -- Do you mean the way you understand the link in my question or your general understanding of Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2):

There is more info about it here http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/ywwzmAx9s-Y

Answer (score 0):

> **Frequency & Recency**   This report lets you see the level of user
>   interest in your site (and by extension your products or services)
>   from the standpoint of how frequently visitors return to your site
>   within a time frame (once, twice, ten times), and how many days go by
>   before they return to your site (do they tend to visit once a week or
>   once a month). Statistics are calculated per unique visitor.
>
> If visitors come once but don't return, you might infer that you're
>   marketing your site to the wrong audience, or that you site content
>   and design are not sufficiently engaging or not easily navigable. If
>   visitors return infrequently, for example, only prior to ski season or
>   only prior to summer, you might decide to expand your portfolio of
>   products to include skis and swimwear; or if you're committed to a
>   single type of product that has seasonal appeal, you can expand your
>   presence to include both hemispheres so you double your winter or
>   summer exposure.
>
> You can use the advanced segments All Visits and Visits with
>   Transactions to see whether the bulk of your transactions occur with
>   one-time visitors or with repeat visitors. If people tend to visit
>   only once yet still make purchases, you can run a promotion like
>   including a gift card that expires within 60 days or offer a different
>   set of specially priced products every week to entice them back.

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1144427